# When does getCssValue and getAttribute return rgba instead of Hex

Tags: protractor

Per the documentation on [getCssValue()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue):

> Where possible, color values will be converted to their hex representation (e.g.#00ff00 instead of rgb(0, 255, 0)).

This has never been the case in our project, it's ALWAYS rgba that is returned.  It's not a big problem because I just use the rgba values in my tests, but I'm looking to understand why it's "not possible" to return hex color in my case?

The only logical answer I can think of is it's how the browser interprets it... however, when I examine these elements I see their hex code in the dev tools.  It shouldn't need to convert the color value at all... It would just be easier for me to grab that value, instead of using a tool to convert hex to rgba every time.

As an example:

```
var elem = $('h2');
expect(elem.getCssValue('color')).toEqual('#F8652A');
// failed test returns: 
Expected 'rgba(248, 101, 42, 1)' to equal '#F8652A'.
```

In what cases would it return the hex code (default), versus the rgba which it seems to return every time for us?

- Protractor v4.0.14
- node v4.2.1
- jasmine v2.5.2
- angular v1.6.2

Comment: Its the same in my App too .. it always return the rgba .. Not sure why !!!